# Linq, How to select even where there is null in joined tables , C# windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, nullable

I have a car table and Owner table. I want to Display them in DataGridView. But my code displays only if Owner field is not null. I want to display all of them
Here is my code , maybe you understand better when you see the code:

```
 var cars = (from u in db.cars
             join o in db.Owner on u.OwnerId equals o.OwnerId
             order by u.carId
             select new
             {
                 CarId = u.CarId,
                 CarName = u.CarName,
                 OwnerName = o.FirstName +" "+ o.FirstName, // Here I want to display owner name or Empty if there is no owner
             }).ToList();

                dgvCars.DataSource = cars;
```

Where is I'am doing wrong? And how should I write my code? u.OwnerId is nulleble in my table. Right now displaying only cars that have Owners. But I want to Display even cars who do not have owner with emptu owner name. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change query to this, you need outer join:

```
var cars = (from u in db.cars
     join o in db.Owner on u.OwnerId equals o.OwnerId into oj
     from o in oj.DefaultIfEmpty()
      order by u.carId
      select new
      {
    CarId = u.CarId,
   CarName = u.CarName,
   OwnerName = o.FirstName==null || o.LastName==null ?"": o.FirstName +" "+ o.LastName, 
       }).ToList();
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I nedded only to add into r2 then from r3 in r2.DefaultIfEmpty()

Answer (score 0):

```
var cars = (from u in db.cars
             join o in db.Owner on u.OwnerId equals o.OwnerId into r2
from r3 in r2.DefaultIfEmpty()
             order by u.carId
             select new
             {
                 CarId = u.CarId,
                 CarName = u.CarName,
                 OwnerName = r3.FirstName +" "+ r3.FirstName,  owner name or Empty if there is no owner
             }).ToList();

                dgvCars.DataSource = cars;
```

Comment: This is practically identical to the answer you selected and serves no purpose other than clutter as it doesn't explain anything. The proper thing to do when you get an answer that works for you is to accept it (like you did), there's no need to post an update